# How to make two windows equally high?

Tags: quickfix

It seems that there is an issue with window-resize with Quickfix list window.

In case of regular window and quickfix list window, how to make them equal in high?

The <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> (and the <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd><kbd>+</kbd>) works, but <kbd>CTRL-W</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> - doesn't work!

Observed in GVIM 8.1 for Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:h winfixheight`

`:h copen`

Quickfix window sets `winfixheight` and 10 lines height by default. `winfixheight` is local to window and makes it not respect your `<c-w>=`.

What you can do is to create an autocmd for quickfix window that will `set nowinfixheight`

smth like:

```
autocmd! BufWinEnter *Quickfix* setlocal nowinfixheight
```

Then after `:copen` and `C-W =` you will have 2 equal windows.